# Using GitLab + Read the Docs for documentation on a Private VM: RTD build fails

Tags: gitlab, python-sphinx, read-the-docs, gitlab-ce

## Background

I am a technical writer trying to use Read the Docs to generate documentation for one of our product. As we have a non-disclosure agreement for any publication, I have to host the documentation on a virtual machine for customers with intranet access to read.

## Installation

### GitLab

My VM is a CentOS 8. I installed GitLab Community Edition through Docker. I created a repository for my Markdown source code under the root account, the address of the repo being `http://${vm_address}/root/${repo_name}`. The GitLab container runs on Port 20 of my VM.

### Read the Docs

As RTD does not officially support On-premise deployment, I pulled an unofficial image from Docker. See [vassilvk/readthedocs](https://hub.docker.com/r/vassilvk/readthedocs). This RTD container runs on Port 8000 of my VM. I use username "admin" to log into RTD.

## Procedure I Took to Integrate GitLab and RTD

To import the source code in my GitLab, I did the following:

1. On the **Project** page, click **Import a Project**.
2. Click **Import Manually** on the left panel.
3. In the **Project Details** page, fill in the fields as follows:

   - Project name: *${my_project_name}*
   - Repository URL: *${Clone_With_HTTP_Address}* `I copied the URL from the "Clone with HTTP" field under the Clone button dropdown in GitLab`
   - Repository Type: Git
4. In the **Advanced Project Options**, I set **Documentation Type** to **Sphinx HTML**.
5. Click **Finish**.

## Result

The build fails with error code `1`.

[image: Failed RTD Build]

## Question

- Where did I do wrong with the RTD project settings?
- Is something wrong going on with my RTD or GitLab container settings?
- Do I still need to install Sphinx on the VM?

Comment: I think you are making this needlessly complicated. Add a hook to your GitLab CI that builds docs using Sphinx and deploys to wherever you want it, without RTD.

Comment: Thanks, Steve. I am about to discuss with a developer about the possibility of using GitLab CI to build and GitLab Page to host my doc.

Comment: @ChinaMahjongKing

May I ask how to solve the problem? Did you use Gitlab CI & Gitlab Page? Are they completely free to use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*As we have a non-disclosure agreement for any publication, I have to host the documentation*

**This does not follow at all.** You must be looking at the wrong ReadTheDocs. There are two sites:

1. ReadTheDocs.org - that one is the free, publicly visible hosting.
2. ReadTheDocs.com - that's the one you want, it hosts private repositories for businesses exactly like yours.

Unless you're in a well managed, secure IT environment, running random Docker images on your own VM will almost certainly lead to inadvertent disclosure. Are you in hosting business? No. Don't play a hosting business when all you want is to write some private documentation. There are products for that.

Comment: Thanks for the comment! The Docker image of RTD I installed on my VM is actually a copy of the free version RTD, because my company is just a start-up and apparently doesn't want to spend the budget on Doc in its early stage. I have removed this random image from my VM and am considering using GitLab page to host my HTML built by an automatic Jenkins Job.